# How to do transpose for trtrs (or tptrs) in blas?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-solver, blas, matrix

How to do transpose for trtrs (or tptrs) in blas?

I want to solve:

```
XA = B
```

But it seems that trtrs only lets me solve:

```
AX = B
```

Or, using the 'transpose' flag, in trtrs:

```
A'X = B
```

which, rearranging is:

```
(A'X)' = B'
X'A = B'
```

So, I can use it to solve XA = B, but I have to first transpose B manually myself, and then, again, transpose the answer.  Am I missing some trick to avoid having to do the two manual transposes?

Note that I've read through [solve $xA=b$ for $x$ using LAPACK and BLAS](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/5318/solve-xa-b-for-x-using-lapack-and-blas) , but it doesn't seem to explain how to avoid the two manual transposes, as far as I can tell?  Or maybe I'm missing something somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since basically all that xTRTRS does is call xTRSM (from BLAS), why not just call that directly? xTRSM contains a SIDE parameter which lets you specify exactly what you want.

Comment: Awesome!  That's the information I was looking for :-)